# Design Pattern Nomenclature & Clarification: Provider, Service, Broker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, naming-conventions

Can someone define for me the conceptual difference is between a Provider, Service and Broker?

I regularly write MVC apps and offload much of the business logic to other classes.  Nothing fancy, just pass in parameters and receive back POCO instance(s).

What is a correct label to give those classes performing the heavy lifting for my controller(s)?

Comment: Interesting question, but (Provider, Service, Broker) refers to naming rules. It is not a design pattern (as you admit in your title)! Do you agree with me?

Comment: It is my understanding that there are Provider and Broker design patterns but I could be wrong.  However, yes, you are correct, my specific question is regarding the naming convention of the behavior I am introducing.  What to name the class(es) to which I am offloading responsibility.

Comment: A broker transfers data or events between other objects. It takes a more active role than (e.g.) a provider, but tends only to be for transfer. Kinda like a real-life broker, it doesn't actually provide services itself.

Comment: I think with this title we are more quickly find the answers. As for me I use provider when class is provides easier work with some classes, (like helper, but as halper I count only simple static classes)

Comment: @Shawn, I added some code to my answer. Because everything is uh... better with code... yeah.

Comment: Just occurred to me that POJO and POCO's are pretty similar, I wonder why people don't call them POOs? For example, *"Nothing fancy, just pass in parameters and receive back POO instance(s)."*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A Provider is really just another name for the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Typically when someone mentions the use of a provider they are talking about some abstract contract to which many implementations could exist.

```
//As an abstract base class
public void SetupRoles(RoleProvider provider){}

//As an interface
public void SetupRoles(IRoleProvider provider){}

//As a delegate
public void SetupRoles(Action<String> addRole){}
```

A Service is usually meant to indicate a stateless object that has only methods on it. A service could be used as a Strategy, but doesn't necessarily have to be.

```
//Plain old service... doesn't even need the web
// CRAZY TALK MAN!!!
public static class RoleService
{
    public static void SetupRoles(){};
    public static String[] GetRoles(){};
}
```

A [Broker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) is really just responsible for well... brokering. It is designed to move messages between services and objects, orchestrating the interactions between services in order to keep them isolated.

```
public class Broker
{
    public void SendImportantMessage(Message msg)
    {
        //Do some important processing here
        // Maybe some validation
        NotifySomeOtherServiceOrClassOrMaybeBobFromAccounting(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Link to the Strategy Pattern doesn't include a single instance of the word "provider" 

Comment: This is one of those situations where "A rose by any other name is still a rose." If you look at the patters they are basically identical. Here is a decent breakdown of what I'm talking about: https://www.simplethread.com/the-provider-model-pattern-really/

Answer (score 5):

These seem to be *architectural patterns* as opposed to *design patterns*;

- [Service oriented architecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)
- [Asp.net patterns every developer should know.](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/8307/aspnet-patterns-every-developer-should-know/)